# converting string to decimal in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, decimal

I am having some problems converting string to decimal values with decimal.parse. 
This is the line of code I have:

```
fixPrice = decimal.Parse(mItemParts.Groups["price"].Value.Replace("$", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("usd", ""));
```

The value from which I am trying to convert is: '$779.99'

Then once the parsing to decimal happens, I am getting this value: 77999.

I would like to get 779.99 instead of 77999. 
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Regex included: "@"\[^\""]+?)\""[^~]+?\]+?src=\""(?[^\""]+?)\""[^>]+?title=\""(?[^\""]+?)\""[^~]+?price\"">(?[^\<]+?)\<[^~]+?\(?[^\<]+?)\

Comment: It looks like you are using a Regular Expression to get the price, what is the expression that you are using?

Comment: @CraigW Regex included. The final product I am getting from the regex is $779.99

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use [`Decimal.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73.aspx):

```
decimal parsedDecimal = 0;
string yourCurrency = "$779.99";
bool didParse = Decimal.TryParse(yourCurrency,
                                 NumberStyles.Currency,
                                 new CultureInfo("en-US"), out parsedDecimal);

if(didParse) {
    // Parse succeeded
}
else {
    // Parse failed
}
```

Comment: `CurrentCulture` might not be the best choice.

Comment: You should check the bool return value of TryParse to see if the parsing succeeded.

Comment: @Commenters, sometimes I think I can sneak a quick and dirty sample in as an answer, then I remember this is SO :). I've updated my answer to reflect your suggestions.

Comment: But this doesn't help the OP, who (1) knows the input string is valid, and (2) has a successful parse that returns an incorrect value.

Comment: @JamesHill: No worries, you still got my vote :).  If I can nitpick again, your comments are wrong :)

Comment: @SteveWong, lol. They weren't before I edited my answer :). I need to stop multi-tasking. Apparently, I'm miserable at it!

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you are running this in a culture where `'.'` is the group separator, and `','` is the decimal separator.  To get around that, use the Parse overload that takes a CultureInfo:

```
fixPrice = decimal.Parse(stringExpression, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Also look into the [`NumberStyles` enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) so you don't have to worry about currency signs yourself:

```
fixPrice = decimal.Parse(stringExpression, NumberStyles.Currency, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: In this way it being made sure that the string format will always be correct. What about `TryParse` ?

Comment: @PankajGarg Of course, `TryParse` is preferable if the OP is not sure whether the input will be valid.

Comment: According to LINQPad, none of these samples work - `FormatException - Input string was not in a correct format`.

Comment: @JamesHill the first sample is supposed to work with "779.99" (as in the OP's example), and for me, it does.  I have corrected the second example (InvariantCulture doesn't use "$" as the currency symbol); thanks for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 2):

Pass a `CultureInfo` instance of the culture you are parsing from.

`CultureInfo` inherits from `IFormatProvider`

**edit:**

Here is a sample for the conversion

```
Decimal.Parse(yourValue, NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol |
                         NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint   |
                         NumberStyles.AllowThousands,
              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: The value is clearly a monetary value; decimal is the more appropriate type.

Comment: If often happens to have values with more than 5 digits to parse.

Comment: @odyodyodys decimal has greater precision than double.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
string decStr = "$779.99";
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
decimal fixPrice = decimal.Parse(decStr, NumberStyles.Currency, ci);
```