# How to convert a string to decimal with 2 decimal places?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to convert a string to a decimal but have the last two values be the decimal point. Example: "001150" be converted into 11.50.

Everything I've found in my search will convert strings to a decimal but the string already has the decimal point. I might have to create a function that will make the decimal point out of the string but wanted to see if there are any other ideas first.

Comment: Convert to decimal, then divide by 100.

Comment: or add the decimal first...Decimal.Parse(str.Insert(str.Length -2, "."));

Comment: Does this answer your question? [converting string to decimal in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145186/converting-string-to-decimal-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    string input = "001150";
    string convertedString = string.Format(
        "{0:N2}",
        double.Parse(input)/100.0
    );
```

Comment: Why are you converting to a `string`? The OP was clear they wanted a `decimal`.

Comment: Initially I did have it as returning a decimal just because it was dealing with money values but I switched it to string. For my case it didn't matter because ultimately it was going to become a string when I wrote it out to another file. My input values are strings but just didn't have a decimal point. Actually, right before I saw this response I was just about finished just using a couple substrings to manipulate and rewrite the value. To me this code looked a little more clean and straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

First check if string is a number, then divide by 100 and then format string:

```
public string ConvertTwoDecimals(string toConvert)
  {
    Double convertedValue;
    var isNumber = Double.TryParse(toConvert, out convertedValue);
    return isNumber ? $"{(convertedValue / 100):N2}" : $"{ 0:N2}";
  }
```

if you need a decimal type without formatted:

```
public decimal ConvertToDecimal(string toConvert)
{
  Decimal convertedValue;
  var isNumber = Decimal.TryParse(toConvert, out convertedValue);
  return isNumber ? convertedValue/100 : 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP wants a `decimal`, not a `string`.

Comment: no, we look to format the string "001150" at 11.50, if you see the answer marked as valid, there they are proposing a string, not a decimal